# cause-specific hazard in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'd like to find a cause-specific hazard function in R as define in the 2nd page of this document: http://data.princeton.edu/pop509/CompetingRisks.pdf

R package 'comrsk' only provides cumulative incidence function.

Is there an R package or function that calculates cause-specific hazard?
Or can I get it from cumulative incidence function?

Comment: You should be able to get it from the cumulative hazard function. Competing hazards estimation is really just a redefinition of what constitutes an event, as that definition on page 2 implies.  So you should also be able to handle this with modifications to your data preparation and the use of ordinary R survival packages. Cancer research is often presented as "recurrence free-survival" which is really turning the event and censoring definitions on their heads. Death becomes a censoring time and recurrence (while alive) becomes the event.

Comment: @BondedDust You said 'you should be able to'..  but I'm asking this because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Tested code requires an example that builds a data-object with either publicly available or created in code. And you need to say what is the "right" answer. If you don't know how to do something in code, then it is often better to search or use CrossValidated.com so that you are in a  position to specify a programming problem.